# How to destructure an object into an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs

I have an object response from an api request. The response gives an object having type and posts.The posts object is an array of 2. The items in the array are objects. I need to map over the posts element.How to do it?

```
{type:'GET_POSTS,
posts:[{id:1,name:John},{id:2,name:Don}]}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: current object is invalid one. please post exact one.

Comment: {type:'GET_POSTS' ,posts:[{id:1,name:John},{id:2,name:Don}]}. I need to map over posts

Comment: yourObject.posts.map(({ id, name }). => { // Do whatever you want with those fields})

Comment: Hi buddy, your object doesn't have a valid structure, did you mean:
`{type:'GET_POSTS', posts:[{id:1,name:'John',text:'hi'},{id:2,name:'Don',message:'hello'}]}` You might want to edit your question to include a correct structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate by map or forEach:

```
const newObj = yourObj.posts.map(item => { do something with the object });
```